# How to pass C# string[] to C char** or char[][]

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, c, swig

in C/C++ I have

```
typedef char TDAStringType[256];

struct CMarketReqMarketDataField
{
    TDACharType         MarketType;                     
    TDACharType         SubscMode;                      
    TDAIntType          MarketCount;                    
    TDAStringType       MarketTrcode[20];   
    TDAStringType       ErrorDescription;               
}
```

Look at the member `MarketTrcode`, It seems stock an array of string/`char *`, but I need to pass values to this struct in C/C++ through C# `string[]` frontend, How can I make it?  using SWIG 4.0.2

Comment: Are you coding this in C or in C++? Please choose one, for the question to stay focused, even if if the is in a .h file which might be included in either. It' s just the nature of this site, you don't want both C and C++ tags in the same question like, ever. If you need both solutions, ask two questions. If solution is same, choose the language you actually use (or use first). Since this probably needs to work in C, I suggest you choose C.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try copying the data into a `byte[][]` on the C# side first?

Comment: Unless you are using something like C++/CLI, you'll want to do this in C (well at least enough to export the endpoint as a C function). If you can find a copy of Adam Nathan's _.NET & COM_ book, it's probably explained in there

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent C# structs for PInvoke marshalling would be

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct TDAStringType
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string String;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct CMarketReqMarketDataField
{
    public char MarketType;                     
    public char SubscMode;                      
    public int MarketCount;                    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public TDAStringType[] MarketTrcode;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string ErrorDescription;
}
```